# OData Data Import/Export Interfacing

Tags: database, wcf, import, odata

We expose an odata service to allow our iOS application to talk to our application MS SQL Server database.

Ive got to look into providing a data import/export facility for our clients to retrieve and update data in the database through the odata service. Im hoping we can provide our clients a simple sdk so they can interface there own data or systems with our system (most of our customers like to interface our application with accounting packages i.e. quicken, myob etc).

Im hoping that someone has done this before and I dont need to recreate the wheel, being that the data is exposed through an open data protocol im wanting to provide the facility to the client as a SDK of sorts so they can take it and do anything that they want to do. Any ideas? Advice?

Thanks